# How to set parameters in .jmx file via Jenkins in Blazemeter test

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

**What I need to do** - create Jenkins job which runs Jmeter test in Blazemeter with some parameters such as a test URL. The parameters should be set in Jenkins before job starts.

**What I have done:**

1. Added [Blazemter plugin](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732669-BlazeMeter-s-Jenkins-Plugin-A-Guide) for Jenkins.
2. Created an appropriate Jenkins job which will use the Blazemeter plugin for building.
3. Created Jmeter scenario and saved it in the .jmx format. I added a variable `${baseURL}` with null value in the Jmeter's test plan which is used in the HTTP request as a `Server Name or IP` value.
4. Created a Jmeter test in Blazemeter and uploaded the jmx file. Saved the test.
5. Tried to run a job with the following parameters described in the session properties field in the Blazemeter plugin `baseURL=${baseURL}`. I set `google.com` as a property value in Jenkins.

**Results** - Blazemeter test has up and ran, it tested `http://` however it had to `http://google.com`.

**So the question is** - What I did wrong or may be the Blazemeter plugin is not what i need or may be general approach is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the following: - use function `__P` or `__property` to get parameters into .jmx file. So i put `${__P(baseURL,)}` function in the Server Name or IP statement and the Blazemeter successfully tested `http://google.com`.